# How to query column matches for a row in a table?

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to figure out how to query the numbers that belong to a particular group in a table for statistic purposes.

The table in question is this:

```
create table MEMBER
  (  id       int           not null,
     name     varchar(10),
     bdate     date,
     sex       char,
     pc_id     int           not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (mid),
   FOREIGN KEY (pc_id) REFERENCES PLEDGECLASS(id))
```

I want to come up with a query that checks all the rows and returns a count of common pc_ids and those corresponding pc_ids.

For example, if the table Member contains the following data:

```
{1,'jon',02091985,'M',02
2,'don',03091985,'M',03
3,'kon',03091985,'M',02
4,'tron',03091985,'M',03)
```

I would want the following to be returned:

```
count     pc_id
2            02
2            03
```

I figured I had to compare two of the same table to figure it out, but that didn't quite work for me. I came up with the following:

```
Select count(p.pc_id), P.pc_id
From   MEMBER p, MEMBER x
Where    p.pc_id=x.pc_id AND NOT p.name = x.name;
```

I know my obvious error with count, but not quite sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) will do the trick

```
Select count(p.pc_id), p.pc_id
From   MEMBER p
Group By p.pc_id
```

Comment: worked perfectly! Thanks! I can't believe i didn't think of that